# WordPress add access for users to edit his comments

Tags: wordpress

How can change comment form to edit comment form for a user who has already submitted a comment for the post?

In my blog, send comment are limited to registered users.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11572456/11447682), such as plugins or using the [edit_comment_link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/edit_comment_link) function?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change the title of the comment then it can be done by **Comment Form Title** plugin. 
Install the plugin and then activate it, after that go to settings and then go to Custom Form Title. On this page you can change the default **comment form title** and insert whatever you want.